# Calculate $\int_\gamma(y^2+z)\,dx + z\, dy + xy\,dz$ where $\gamma$ is the intersection between two surfaces.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

The problem I have is to find the normal vextor $\textbf{N}$, for Stokes's theorem, and then determine the area of integration.

Here's the question:

Let $\gamma$ be the intersection between the surfaces $z=x^2 + y^2$ and $z=1-y^2$.

Calculate $$\int_\gamma(y^2+z)\,dx + z\, dy + xy \,dz$$

Now $\gamma$ is a closed curve and hence I can use Stokes's theorem.

Let $\textbf{u}=(y^2+z,z,xy)$, then $\operatorname{curl} \textbf{u} = (x-1,1-y,-2y)$

How do I continue from here?

Thanks! Alexander